# Jira rest api get issue attachment via python

Tags: python-3.x, jira, jira-rest-api

So, I need to download attachments to the issue in Jira using python. I have next code

```
from atlassian import Jira

issue = jira.issue(issuekey, fields='summary,comment,attachment')

for attachment in issue['fields']['attachment']:
with open((attachment.filename), 'wb') as file:
    file.write(attachment.get(b'', b''))
```

After running the code I'm getting 3 empty files(txt, png, png) without any data inside..

How can I get(download) files from issue to my current folder?

Comment: `attachment.get()` ?

Comment: @Rakesh when I'm using just attachment.get() I'm getting an issue: `TypeError: get expected at least 1 arguments, got 0`

Answer (score 4):

Try using `expand="attachment"`

**Ex:**

```
issue = jira.issue(issuekey,  expand="attachment")

for attachment in issue['fields']['attachment']:
    with open(attachment.filename, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(attachment.get())
```

Comment: Unfortunately I got issue() got an unexpected keyword argument 'expand'

Comment: Are you using `jira-python` ?

Comment: sure, as I mentioned at the top of topic

Comment: no I mean the name of library used to connect to JIRA from python

Comment: when I'm printing 'file', then I get normal name of the files inside the issue.

Comment: definitely, if I'm getting data it means that it's okey

Comment: one more mistake in your code, I can't use attachment.filename because attachment has no object filename and as the result I need to write attachment['filename']

Answer (score 2):

You need the link to the contents of the attachment which is stored under the key 'content'. Then just use `.get()` request, that is in Jira library:

```
for attachment in issue['fields']['attachment']:
    link = attachment['content']
    link = link.split("https://jira.companyname.com/")[1]
    b_str = jira.get(link, not_json_response=True)
    with open((attachment['filename']), 'wb') as file:
        file.write(b_str)
```

Notice that you need to trim the link, because `jira.get()` automatically includes the domain to the request url.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the attachment details:
2. get the jira attachment file URL
3. download the file using Request Module.
4. Check the file in file list.

```js
            issue = jira.issue(jira_ticket, expand='changelog')
            attach = issue.fields.attachment
            file_url = attach[0].content
            file_path = "filename"
            r = requests.get(file_url, auth=('jira_user', 'jira_pass'))
            with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(r.content)
```